# Meteor how to create copy of file in CollectionFS?

Tags: javascript, meteor, gridfs, collectionfs

I need to create copy one of record in my FS.Collection ...

I am able to fetch record by

```
var oldFile = Attachment.find({ _id : cardId });
var newFile = oldFile.copy();
```

Above code doesn't work for me

I have following packages installed in my Meteor project

```
aldeed:collection2
cfs:gridfs
cfs:standard-packages
```

But I am not able to use FS.File.copy method as it gives error of undefined function in my helper method of template. (running on client side)